# UNTextInputNotificationAction set keybaord to number pad

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, keyboard

I have set up UNTextInputNotificationAction, in my iOS app in the app delegate, but I am unable to change the keybaord to the number pad, it doesn't seem available in any of the options, yet I see other apps that have done this.

Here are my actions

```
let accept = UNNotificationAction(
identifier: "accept",
title: "Accept")

let add = UNTextInputNotificationAction(
identifier: "add_value",
title: "Add value")

let category = UNNotificationCategory(
identifier: categoryIdentifier,
actions: [accept, add],
intentIdentifiers: [])

UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
  .setNotificationCategories([category])
```

How can I set the keyboard for the notification input?

Comment: What did you call the textField where the numbers are supposed to be entered?

Answer (score -3):

You could try using the UIKeyboard type: read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype). You might say

```
textInputPlaceholder.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
```

Comment: where would I put that line? The above lines in my question are in `didFinisihLaucnhingWithOptions`

Comment: You could put this in your viewDidLoad function.

Comment: viewDidLoad in what?